# Matrix template class

Tags: java, class, templates, generics

I would like to write a small mathematical library for matrices. The key variable of the class is obviously the field of entries. 
Having written a class for fractions and complex numbers, I was wondering whether I could exploit generic programming in order to escape the need to write the same class over and over again.

So, I have several basic classes for fractions, algebraic numbers, complex numbers etc.
I would like to make them types for my template class matrix, where ? can be anything out of the bunch of complex, algebraic, fraction numbers etc.
Would it help to lump the elegible types into one super class (e.g. 'mymath', with the consequence that '? extends mymath' in the declaration?

Is that possible in an elegant manner? Which conditions does the 'mymath' class have to meet?

Answer (score 1):

there is a complete important package for matrices processing named **jama** that you can find here http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/#Package .

Comment: Thank you very much for your link. I forgot to mention that I am aware of the Jama/Jampack libraries and its limitations. Whilst having many advantages, it seems to be clearly geared towards numerical application - entries are double by default, which is frustrating if you are interested in exact solutions. 

I have to add that in the meantime, I noticed that interfaces might be what I am looking for.

Comment: I understood your question, and I just want to show you jama package. it is very important what you are thinking about